# Custom Taxonomy Archive generates 404

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

I have a custom post type called "artists". Attached to this is a custom taxonomy, `genre`.

Now, URLs `/genre/<post slug>` works perfectly fine, however the naked taxonomy page `/genre/` gives a 404 error, and I'm struggling to find the error in my code that would do this.

This is my code:

```
// Genre
add_action( 'init', '_ct_genre', 0 );
function _ct_genre() {
    $label_p = 'Genrer';
    $label_s = 'Genre';
    register_taxonomy( 'genre', 'artists', array(
        'labels'                    => array(
            'name'                      => $label_p,
            'singular_name'             => $label_s,
            'menu_name'                 => $label_p,
            'all_items'                 => 'Alla ' . strtolower($label_p),
            'parent_item'               => 'Förälder',
            'parent_item_colon'         => 'Förälder:',
            'new_item_name'             => 'Nytt namn på ' . strtolower($label_s),
            'add_new_item'              => 'Ny ' . strtolower($label_s),
            'edit_item'                 => 'Redigera ' . strtolower($label_s),
            'update_item'               => 'Uppdatera ' . strtolower($label_s),
            'search_items'              => 'Sök ' . strtolower($label_p),
            'add_or_remove_items'       => 'Lägg till eller Ta bort ' . strtolower($label_p)
        ),
        'hierarchical'              => false,
        'public'                    => true,
        'show_ui'                   => true,
        'show_admin_column'         => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'         => true,
        'has_archive'               => true,
        'show_tagcloud'             => true,
        'update_count_callback'     => '_update_post_term_count',
        'query_var'                 => true,
        'publicly_queryable'        => true,
        'rewrite'                   => array(
            'slug'                      => 'genre',
            'with_front'                => true,
            'hierarchical'              => true
        )
    ) );
}
```

All similar issues on StackExchange that I have found, does not apply here.

- I've tried setting `query_var` to a string 'genre' instead, however that didn't work either.
- I have of course flushed permalinks after each and every change.

Comment: After some more googling, I realize that this is default WP behaviour, as this answer states: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/235450/custom-taxonomy-archive-page. It's very unsatisfying, and I'd like to have to resolved. So if anyone has any ideas, I'm all ears.

Comment: `has_archive` is for `register_post_type()` and not `register_taxonomy()`. Have you tried `'has_archive' => 'genre'` with `register_post_type()`? That will give you a *custom post type **archive*** accessible at `example.com/genre`. However, the posts being displayed would be from any taxonomies attached to the post type.

Comment: Yes I realize has_archive is for CPTs, not taxonomies. I merely did a test and forgot to remove it.

Comment: An option I see possible is by creating a standard Page, give it the slug `genre` and assign it to a *custom template*, and in that template, you can run a custom SQL like [this](https://gist.github.com/5ally/c0e595f03f88978b4378a32d99ee1e86#file-custom-query-sql). Or you can try `tax_query` with the `terms` set to term IDs of terms in the `genre` taxonomy - [example](https://gist.github.com/5ally/c0e595f03f88978b4378a32d99ee1e86#file-custom-query-php).

Comment: @SallyCJ That is essentially what I ended up doing :-) Although a custom SQL query isn't necessary. WP_query does everything that's needed.

Comment: I couldn't agree more, and you might want to share your solution as an answer. :)

Comment: @SallyCJ I would, except my solution is out of scope of my original question, I think.